# Determine size of the screen in Wayland C++

Tags: c++, linux, wayland

I have to write several functions which do some things with the user screen like gettings screen resolution, count of monitors etc. I have working solution for Windows and Linux, but on Linux I'm stuck with Wayland. On X11 size of the screen can be easily determined, but Wayland is relatively new and not so documented as X11.

I've tried the following code:

```
static void global_handler(void* data, wl_registry* registry, uint32_t name,
                           const char* interface, uint32_t version) {
    wl_output* output = static_cast<wl_output*>(
        wl_registry_bind(registry, name, &wl_output_interface, 1));
    if (!output) {
        // Handle error
    }
}

    std::string GetDisplaySize(std::string args) {

        if (getenv("WAYLAND_DISPLAY") != nullptr) {

            static std::uint16_t width, height;

            wl_display* display = wl_display_connect(nullptr);
            if (!display) { return "0"; }

            wl_registry* registry = wl_display_get_registry(display);

            static const wl_registry_listener registry_listener = {
                .global = +[](void* data, wl_registry* registry, uint32_t name,
                              const char* interface, uint32_t version) -> void {
                    wl_output* output = static_cast<wl_output*>(
                        wl_registry_bind(registry, name, &wl_output_interface,
                                         1));
                    if (!output) { return; }

                    wl_output_get_geometry(output, nullptr, nullptr, &width,
                                           &height);

                    wl_output_destroy(output);
                },
                .global_remove =
                    [](void* data, wl_registry* registry, uint32_t name) {
                    },
            };
            wl_registry_add_listener(registry, &registry_listener, nullptr);

            wl_display_roundtrip(display);

            wl_display_disconnect(display);

            return "{\"width\":" + std::to_string(width) +
                   ",\"height\":" + std::to_string(height) + "}";
        } // namespace api
        else {
            GdkRectangle workarea = {0};
            gdk_monitor_get_workarea(
                gdk_display_get_primary_monitor(gdk_display_get_default()),
                &workarea);

            return "{\"width\":" + std::to_string(workarea.width) +
                   ",\"height\":" + std::to_string(workarea.height) + "}";
        }
    }
```

This works for X11, but on Wayland I get compiler error

```
error: ‘wl_output_get_geometry’ was not declared in this scope
```

I'm using GCC C++ compiler. I tried to find some info about that `wl_output_get_geometry` or which function I can use instead, but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: When I Google wl_output_get_geometry the only search result is your question. Perhaps you are supposed to use wl_output_add_listener to add a listener.